# Возможно ли как то ускорить MySQL-connector в python?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

Пишу программу, она предполагает большое количество запросов к бд. `Python 3.11`, `MySQL 8` +- последний, `mysql-connector-python` последний с `pip`а.

Обнаружил, что один простой `SELECT` к таблице на 30 строк обрабатывается на 2 порядка дольше, чем все мои измышления в области кода.

Я, конечно, сейчас пытаюсь заоптимизировать так, чтобы запросов стало поменьше, но...
Чую я тут узкое место, на котором программа начнет тормозить с ожидаемым ростом количества запросов.

И избавиться от них переведя все данные в программу я не могу, там ожидаются изменения в базе из других источников, которые надо будет учитывать.

Что я могу предпринять для ускорения выполнения запросов? Какие то настройки коннектора и mysql'а? Переход на какой то другой коннектор? Или радикальнее - переход на другую субд? Таблички прям обычные-обычные, разве что нужен множественный параллельный доступ.

Код, в общем то, тоже простой и стандартный, со всяких мануалов:

```py
# pip install -U mysql-connector-python
# Обновлен до последней версии
from mysql.connector import connect


with connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='',) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        select_query = "SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 5;"
        cursor.execure(select_query)
        value = cursor.fetchone()[0]

        select_query = "SELECT value FROM table WHERE name ='Столик';"
        cursor.execure(select_query)
        value = cursor.fetchone()[0]

        select_query = f"SELECT value FROM table WHERE date < {datetime.now()};"
        cursor.execure(select_query)
        value = cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

PS копался-копался, возможно я был не прав с вычислением источника проблем. Пойду дальше копаться.

Comment: *Обнаружил, что один простой SELECT к таблице на 30 строк обрабатывается на 2 порядка дольше, чем все мои измышления в области кода.* С момента намерения послать запрос до момента получения обработанного кодом результата запроса проходит несколько этапов - установить соединение, послать запрос, на сервере запрос выполнить, отправить ответ на клиента, там принять, распарсить, обработать... какой или какие этапы тормозят?

Comment: @Akina У меня есть другая программа, на +- тех же условиях, правда там запросов мало и мне было не критично. На данный момент могу сказать, что подобный `SELECT` к таблице в 55к строк не выполняется в 5к раз больше времени, чем запрос к таблице в 10 строк. Из этого по идее можно сделать вывод что это не обработка таблицы на стороне mysql'а. Программа и MySQL крутятся на одном компьютере, `connect(host='localhost')`, когда я мерил время я считал уже чисто выполнение строк с самим `SELECT`ом. Как я могу померить оставшиеся места?

Comment: Зачем `fetchall`, если вы берёте одну запись, тогда `fetchone` вроде используется. Зачем `commit`, если вы не пишете в базу. И первым делом проверяйте сколько времени работает запрос при непосредственном обращении к базе, без всяких питонов. Вот когда это отладите и убедитесь, что запрос работает быстро, тогда уже нужно разбираться с библиотеками питона, но не раньше. Может у вас большая таблица, а индекса по `id` нет? Всяко же бывает. Или, например, в таблицу кто-то непрерывно пишет и она всё время лочится, поэтому запросы на чтение всё время ждут. Ну, короче, сценариев много можно придумать.

Comment: @CrazyElf 1) это был пример. Просто в большинстве случаев у меня там таки больше одного, вот и пихнул, не подумал. Поправил. 2) а вот эту отладку через что посоветуете делать? в воркбэнче какие то функции времени есть? 3) В тестовой таблице типа 30 строк и ее никто кроме меня не трогает. И, там по идее значительная часть запросов пойдет не по id. Или индекс по id повлияет даже если идет запрос с `WHERE Name = 'Столик'`?

Comment: *SELECT к таблице в 55к строк не выполняется в 5к раз больше времени, чем запрос к таблице в 10 строк.* Сильно смахивает на то, что узкое место - передача данных от сервера на клиента (сеть) либо размещение/парсинг принимаемой клиентом информации.

Comment: @Akina оно на данный момент все на одном компе крутится. Доступ к базе через `localhost` под `root` акком.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 Так вы понимаете вообще, что эффективность выполнения запроса с `WHERE` зависит от того, есть ли в базе индексы по тем полям, по которым вы ставите ограничения в `WHERE`? И что текстовые поля довольно плохо индексируются, особенно если они большие. Не знаю как в воркбенче, вы можете и сами таймером засечь, сколько времени запрос выполняется. Но обычно программы для интерактивного доступа к базе где-то в окошке пишут, сколько времени запрос выполнялся.

Comment: *Доступ к базе через localhost под root акком.* Network? Socket? Shared memory?

Comment: @Akina Ставил MySQL Installer'ом, конфиг Development Computer, все настройки по умолчанию.

Comment: Вы предлагаете мне выполнить такую установку и посмотреть, что получилось, что ли?

Comment: @Akina Нет, я просто не очень понял где и как это посмотреть. Вот как я это ставил, ничего похожего не видел.

Comment: @Akina Ну, судя по строке коннекта это просто сетевой коннект `host='localhost'`

Comment: "Пойду дальше копаться." - нам потом расскажите, интересно же, в чём дело было ))  А может у вас просто память кончилась и комп сваповал? )

Comment: @CrazyElf расскажу. Меня тут немного другим напрягли, так что о сроках ничего точно сказать не могу. По памяти - 12гб, вин11, открыт pycharm, в фоне сервисом висит mysql 8 на десяток таблиц, самая большая на 200 строк. Как то я не вижу где здесь 12гб могут закончиться, хм...

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 С `PyCharm` может закончиться всё, что угодно ))  Шучу, но штука своеобразная. Так то 200 строк ни о чём, на 200 строк действительно могут и индексы не делать в базе, если вся таблица в память влезает.

Answer (score 3):

with connect убирай и используй пул конектов.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

Сам пул клади где-то глобально и доставай оттуда готовые коннекты.

Comment: И как это должно ускорить? Я доработал пример, там как бы все запросы под одним коннектом идут. Или из пула коннектов каждый раз новый брать будет быстрее?

Comment: Программа работает в фоне или запускается разово?

Comment: Работает в фоне. Один раз подключилась и висит. Хотя я крутил по разному, могу сказать что тормоз происходит НЕ во время самого `with connect`, а именно в то время когда я делаю `cursor.execute`. PS Хм, надо будет покрутить так-сяк, на что уходит больше времени - на `execute` или на `fetchall/one`. Как то я их вместе считал, хм...

Comment: А в голом MySQL , в консоле, оно быстрее работает?